# C# list collection loses its value outside of method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to C# and the ASP.NET framework and can't seem to find an answer as to why the values added to a list collection in one method either disappear or can't be accessed in another method. If I print the contents of the list right after it is created, the values are returned, but the debugger says there's nothing in the list   after the list has been created and accessed in a different method.

This is the class that is the datatype for the list:

```
class Letter
{
    public char Character { get; set; }
    public bool Guessed { get; set; }
}
```

This is the list being declared (the printing out at the end does work):

```
private List<Letter> currentWord = new List<Letter>();
```

This is the method creating the list:

```
protected void CreateCurrentWordList()
    {
        char[] letterArray = computerChoice.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < letterArray.Length; i++)
        {
            currentWord.Add(new Letter { Character = letterArray[i], Guessed = false });
        }
        string displayString = PrintCurrentWord();
        TestLabel.Text = displayString;
    }
```

And this is the code block in another method that can't access the values inserted into the list or where the list shows up as empty in the debugger:

```
foreach (Letter letter in currentWord)
            {
                if (letter.Character.ToString() == userGuess)
                {
                    letter.Guessed = true;
                    displayString += letter.Character.ToString();
                }                   
            }
```

Thanks for any help or direction to another post answering this question.

EDIT: Adding static keyword to list collection declaration seems to have solved the problem. Thanks PiJei!

Comment: How does the code go from one method to another?

Comment: just as a terminology comment, `char[]` is an array, not a list (though I don't think this makes much difference in your case)

Comment: Can you post complete method for "PrintCurrentWord"

Comment: This code is not enough to understand your problem. Is the List declared at the class level. Is the initialization of the list done in the Page_Load method? The second code block is called from some event handler in your ASPX page? Do you reinitialize the list at every Page_Load?

Comment: If you make the calls to these functions in separate runs, you may need to make your list static.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, everyone. PiJei's comment about making the list static seems to have worked, so thanks PiJei! Could anyone tell me why? Should all variables or collections that you want to persist values in a browser session be static?

Comment: This code is running on the server? Then making it static is probably a bad idea. If you have information that needs to be persisted for the duration of a user's session then it needs to go in session state!

Comment: What makes the static keyword especially dangerous in server code is that everything will work fine if there is only one client...which is often the case during testing.

Answer (score 0):

It could be for many reasons:

1. You have two or more objects instantiated and one of them has no values in it.
2. You are using the block code of the method that can't access the
   values before adding values to the list.
3. You postback the page losing the data in the list.

I would try storing *currentWord* in a **ViewState["myList"]** to see if it has values after some requests.